# MVC C# creating username password

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to create MVC project that include username password authentication. But I don't know how can I do this. I will not use database. Just make it with getter setter. I will do this in a model class also. My getter setter is inside. I have to predefine some username password also. I write username password in a text and I also add it into a question.Thank you for any idea

```
    public class Response
{   
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}

    <form asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
    <p>
        <label asp-for="Username">Username : </label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Username" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <label asp-for="Password">Password : </label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Password" type="password" />
    </p>

    <button class="submit" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically in your view use your model and Html helpers :

```
@model Response

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationFor(m=>m.Username)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserName)
   <button class="submit" type="submit">Login</button>
}
```

That way when you submit the form, `Response` is passed to the controller with data inside.

Comment: What doesn't work? Please edit your question and post your entire code.

Comment: Let me explain my code request. In my MVC project, I have a form and I enter username and password in the label as you can see. I also need to predefine username password couples like user and 123 . In controller I try to do this with dictionary it gives no error but it didn't work. I couldn't share code because it is too long for this place

Comment: [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Index(Response response)
        {Dictionary<String, String> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dictionary.Add("user1", "123");
            if (ModelState.IsValid && dictionary.Keys.Equals(response.Username) && dictionary.Values.Equals(response.Password))  {
                Repository.AddResponse(response);
                return View("Main", response);
       }else
            {
              return View() }